# Change class "data-value" with plus / minus buttons?

Tags: javascript, input, attributes, gauge

so all tutorials show how to change a simple input "value" with plus and minus buttons.

This is my question, how do I change a class "data-value"?

```js
$(document).on('click','.value-control',function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action')
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target')
    var dataValue  = parseFloat($('[id="'+target+'"]').val());
    if ( action == "plus" ) {
      value++;
    }
    if ( action == "minus" ) {
      value--;
    }
    $('[id="'+target+'"]').data("value", (value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- I want to change the "data-value" value here (it's a meter gauge lots of JS -->

<div class="gauge" id="guagechanger" data-plugin="gauge" data-value="1" data-min-value="1" data-max-value="10" data-stroke-color="#f978a6">
         <div class="gauge-label"></div>
         <canvas width="200" height="150"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- my plus and minus buttons -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-floating btn-danger value-control" data-action="minus" data-target="guagechanger"><i class="icon wb-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-floating btn-danger value-control" data-action="plus" data-target="guagechanger"><i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: jQueries `data` is different from HTML's `dataset`. jQuery just takes the initial values from HTML and then works completely on its own.

Comment: Okay, so i need to change jQueries data, not HTML dataset. Confusing! Any ideas?

Comment: Where is that element that has the ID `target`? **PS:** you can select it using this `$('#' + target)` instead of `$('[id="'+target+'"]')`. It's short! Pluse you're storing the value inside the variable `dataValue` then you use `value` which is undefined.

Comment: im guessing my div class="gauge" id="guagechanger"  should be div class="gauge" id="target"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close,

just instead of going to target.val() you need to go to taget.data('value'),
and you got confused a little bit with the variable names.

here is a working snippet

```js
$(document).on('click','.value-control',function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    var value  = parseFloat($('#'+target).data('value'));
    if ( action == "plus" ) {
      value++;
    }
    if ( action == "minus" ) {
      value--;
    }
    console.log(value);
    $('#'+target).data("value", (value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- I want to change the "data-value" value here (it's a meter gauge lots of JS -->

<div class="gauge" id="guagechanger" data-plugin="gauge" data-value="1" data-min-value="1" data-max-value="10" data-stroke-color="#f978a6">
         <div class="gauge-label"></div>
         <canvas width="200" height="150"></canvas>
</div>

<!-- my plus and minus buttons -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-floating btn-danger value-control" data-action="minus" data-target="guagechanger"><i class="icon wb-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-floating btn-danger value-control" data-action="plus" data-target="guagechanger"><i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

According with jquery [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) :

```
var target = $(this).data('target');
```

For change data attributes :

```
$(this).data('target', value);
```